# Constant changes in terraform plan due to parsing of regex pattern matching string

Tags: terraform, gitlab

I'm trying to automatically set container expiration policies for gitlab project containers from terraform. Here is the field where there's an issue:

```
resource "gitlab_project" "project" {
  container_expiration_policy {
    # set the regex for which the policy applies
    name_regex = "dev\\..+"
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that if you go into the repo, this string input in the terraform gets parsed into the string `"dev..*"`. So there's some processing of the string that's input in the terraform files.

The result of this is that every time you make a minor change in the project, then the project plan detects 100+ changes, where the logs look something like this:

```
 ~ container_expiration_policy {
    ~ name_regex        = "dev..*" -> "dev\\..+"
```

Is there any way to avoid this string parsing? Such that the exact string input in the terraform file is the one that appears in the gitlab settings? This would make it more clear as well as avoiding hundreds of "changes" in each plan.

This is the gitlab provider used:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    gitlab = {
      source  = "gitlabhq/gitlab"
      version = "=16.0.3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can maybe try using `lifecycle { ignore_changes = [name_regex] }`, but not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: If you are certain that your regex is correct and is not being auto-corrected by the provider, then you probably would want to raise an issue on the provider tracker.